# Using the Google ChromeosDevices API - "Bad Request" error

Tags: oauth, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, bad-request

I am currently trying to get a list of chrome devices for a given user that has authorized my application to have access to the device meta data.  I have formatted my request as this page suggests:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/list#try-it

However, that try-it feature fails with any input I give it, even when using the OAuth 2.0.  I tend to get a "Bad Request" error when specifying a user id and a "Not authorized to access this resource" when using my_customer as the id input.

Seeing this, I was hoping it would work when I made a request of my own with the proper headers AND specifying the api key (a "key" value passed in as a GET parameter and didn't seem to be specified in the example).  However no luck.

Anyone else having issues with this or a possible solution?  There seems to be very little documentation on this feature of the API.